# Can't export Vietnamese characters to PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, itext

I'm trying to export Vietnamese characters to PDF using iText. I tried to use

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

It displays some unicode characters correctly, for example Russian, but not the ones with accents in Vietnamese language (ạ,ã,ố etc.).
Here's the class I wrote:

```
public class PDFMaker {
private final static String FILE = "FilePdf.pdf";
public static File fontFile = new File("fonts/arialuni.ttf");
public static void makePDF() throws IOException{
    try{    
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(bf,15);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Đại học bách khoa Hà Nội", font)); 
        document.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }}
```

It displays: Đi hc bách khoa Hà Ni. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters aren't shown, because MS Arial Unicode doesn't know those characters. You need to use another font. For instance: I downloaded [a package of Vietnames fonts from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vietunicode/files/VietFonts-Web1/Web1%20Package%20v2004/VietFontsWeb1_ttf.zip/download) and I replaced arialuni.ttf in your code sample with vuArial.ttf (found in the downloaded package). When using that font, all the characters were visible.